# Нужно совместить эффект аккордеона и табов в одном скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Хочу немного модифицировать этот скрипт, чтобы из активного элемента switch tab разворачивался его контент, сейчас это работает не верно (раскрываются сразу все).

Делал решение на css с привязкой раскрытия к активному элементу, но даже с transition раскрытие/скрытие выглядит не плавно, поэтому решил попробовать со слайдами.

```js
$(".content").not(":first").hide();
$(".switch:first div").show();
$(".switch").click(function() {

  var sld = $(".switch div");

  $(".switch").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
  $(".content").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();

  if ($(".switch").eq($(this).index()).hasClass("active")) {
    sld.slideDown();
  } else {
    sld.slideUp();
  }
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```css
.switch span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.switch div {
  display: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.active span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch_wr">
  <div class="switch">
    <span>Switch_1</span>
    <div>Some text switch tab 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="switch">
    <span>Switch_2</span>
    <div>Some text switch tab 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="switch">
    <span>Switch_3</span>
    <div>Some text switch tab 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_wr" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="content">some content 1</div>
  <div class="content">some content 2</div>
  <div class="content">some content 3</div>
</div>
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете вот так сделать:

```
 $('.switch div').each(function( index ) {
   var sld = $(this); 
   sld.slideUp(); 
 });

 if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { 
   var sld = $(this).find('div'); 
   sld.slideDown(); 
 }
```

**Полный код Jquery:**

```
(function($) {
    $(".content").not(":first").hide();
    $(".switch:first div").show();
    $(".switch").click(function() {

    $(".switch").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
        $(".content").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(); 

        $('.switch div').each(function( index ) {
            var sld = $(this); 
            sld.slideUp(); 
        });

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { 
            var sld = $(this).find('div'); 
            sld.slideDown(); 
        } 
    }).eq(0).addClass("active");
})( jQuery );
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даниил, будь другом выложи весь код и опиши разницу, я JQ дружу и не понял куда этот кусок вставить.  Просто для практики...

Comment: @Air так лучше?

Comment: Даниил, благодарю...  Мне просто чужой код читать трудно, особенно JQ

Comment: @Даниил Благодарю, отличное решение.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev, ответ принял, спасибо сказал...  Поставь, сделай добро поставь плюсик человеку....)))

Comment: Рад что помог, и вам спасибо )