# Как реализовать разворачивание accordion jQuery Ui наверх и вниз?

Tags: jquery-ui

Доброго времени суток. Я использую jQuery UI - accordion и по умолчанию при нажатии на одну из вкладок выезжает только вниз, а мне необходим выезд наверх и вниз

```
$(function() {$("#accordion_2").accordion({
 heightStyle: "content",
 active: false,
 collapsible: true }); });
```

Comment: [Может поможет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743060/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5/743071#743071)

Comment: ну там расходится только вниз, а мне нужно еще и наверх

Comment: https://us.fashionbunker.com/phase-top-ivory если не будет работать так как я объяснял, просто уменьшите ширину окна браузера и тот аккордион должен будет встать влево

Comment: не совсем, при закрытых всех при нажатии разъезжает в обе стороны, мне нужно сделать так же

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ вот выезжает только в одну сторону

Comment: Написал пример в ответе, посмотрите то не то, если нет, прошу более подробно описать. Для просмотра нажмите "Выполнить код"

Comment: Напишите собственный. С такой функцией. В том плагине такой функции нет.